# How can I stop this Internet Explorer dialog box from popping up?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, user-profile

A user of mine uses Remote Desktop to access an application. When they print from this application, it opens a PDF in Internet Explorer 11.

Each day they do this, the "Set up Internet Explorer 11" dialog box appears. They click the "OK" button, but the next day, it pops up again.

[image: Set up Internet Explorer 11]

The server the application is running on is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard SP1.
Internet Explorer Version 11.0.9600.19596

There is an event in the Event Viewer that might be relevant:

```
Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.
```

EDIT (2020-02-28):

The profile is not listed in `Control Panel\System and Security\System` > `Advanced system settings`  > `User Profiles`: `Settings`.

When I open the Registry Editor and expand

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

The user's profile is listed as:
`S-#-#-##-##########-##########-##########-####.bak`

The `ProfileImagePath` is set to C:\Users\*username*

That folder doesn't exist in windows.

There is a folder in `C:\Users\` called "*username*.5-9-2016"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check the message and found that the issue is not actually about the IE browser. But there is some issue with the user profile. Every time Windows is loading a temporary profile which cannot keep the changes made by users. that's why IE shows setup dialog every time.

This event can be caused by the following issues:

1. Your local profile is corrupt. You no longer have adequate privileges to the profile folders.
2. User profile was deleted manually or by other means. A profile that is manually deleted does not remove the Security Identifier (SID) from the profile list in the registry.
3. If the SID is present, Windows will try to load the profile by using the ProfileImagePath that points to a nonexistent path. Therefore, the profile cannot be loaded.
4. Occasionally, Windows might not read your user profile correctly, for example, if your antivirus software is scanning your computer while you try to log on.

**Resolutions**

Sign out and restart the computer

Try restarting your computer and signing on with your user account again to resolve the issue.

Delete the error SID and create a new profileR

**Resolve this problem yourself, follow these steps:**

1. Delete the profile by using the Computer Properties dialog box. To do this, follow these steps:

   - Click Start, right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
   - Click Change settings.
   - In the System Properties dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
   - Under User Profiles, click Settings.
   - In the User Profiles dialog box, select the profile that you want to delete, click Delete, and then click OK.
2. Click Start Collapse this imageExpand this image, type regedit in the Start search box, and then press ENTER.
3. Locate and then expand the following registry subkey:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

4. Right-click the SID that you want to remove, and then click Delete.
5. Sign in to the computer and create a new profile.

Reference:

[Windows -User Profiles Service Event 1511: Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3571.windows-user-profiles-service-event-1511-windows-cannot-find-the-local-profile-and-is-logging-you-on-with-a-temporary-profile.aspx)

Comment: See edits for more information regarding your response. For step 5, how does one create a new profile?

Comment: You can try to refer steps for creating a user account from this link. https://www.mustbegeek.com/create-user-account-in-windows-server-2008-r2/#.Xl3_W6gzaUk Then try to log in on that account will create new user profile.

Comment: The user's account is a domain account so I cannot create a new one for her. The problem is when she is remoting to a certain machine, it's not using her user profile, instead it's using a temporary one.

Comment: I am limited to provide support for Microsoft browsers. I can see that this issue is actually not related to the IE browser. So I may not able to provide you the best support experience. For better support, I suggest you create a support ticket for Microsoft. one engineer will be assigned to look into your issue. Thanks for your understanding.